# Mysql Multi Delete with EVENT

Tags: php, mysql

i've ben wondering how to do auto delete with event if the record is older than 3 minutes, so the record is delete when 3 minutes and status='BELUM BAYAR'

i've try this code, but its not working guys

here my code

```
 DELETE `pembayaran`, `detail_pemesanan`, `pemesanan`, `pelanggan` 
 FROM `pembayaran`, `detail_pemesanan`, `pemesanan`, `pelanggan`  
 where pembayaran.`status`='BELUM DIBAYAR' 
   AND pemesanan.`tanggal` < (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)
```

can someone help me with this issue?

[image]

Comment: You need to define an event. Google *mysql events*

Comment: i've try this query 
DELETE pembayaran ,detail_pemesanan, pemesanan, pelanggan FROM pembayaran, detail_pemesanan, pemesanan, pelanggan  where pembayaran.status='BELUM DIBAYAR' AND (NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MINUTE) and its work, but the timer not work

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html

Comment: i use phpmyadmin to create event, with GUI, i cant get the column date creation. example. if column date > older than 3 minutes its delete

Comment: `... AND column_date < (NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MINUTE)`

Comment: its not work with event, must be column_date < column_date - INTERVAL 3 MINUTE) or something :(

Comment: Well in your screenshot the errors highlighted are at the beginning with your table names. And BTW you don't even join proberly there. You used the correct join sytax in your question though

Comment: yeah my bad, i end up not using join, you may check again

Comment: the screenshot highlighted but when i click "go" its success not error

Comment: If `column_date < (NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MINUTE)` does not work for you then you really need to add example data and expected output into your question

Comment: il try date_column >  (date_column + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE) but its not working